# Any recommendation on republish an endpoint to remain same

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

For AzureML we’re using the REST api provided in published pipelines to launch them as part of scheduled jobs.

It looks like if we republish an endpoint the GUID at the end of the URL changes.
Do you have any recommendations for how to alias this so the URL can remain the same for a caller or keep it constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are static, unique URLs that can be associated with multiple published pipeline versions (you can make one pipeline the default).

Pipeline Endpoints:[azureml.pipeline.core.PipelineEndpoint class - Azure Machine Learning Python | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-pipeline-core/azureml.pipeline.core.pipelineendpoint?view=azure-ml-py)